# Python win32api.SetCursorPos dual screen issue

Tags: python, winapi, wxpython, mousemove

I am trying to create simple program which will click to specific coordinates every x seconds based on your choose if you need to click on Left screen or Right screen. My issue here is that **win32api.SetCursorPos** which is moving with my cursor is not moving to the secondary screen (right in my case). It stays in the main screen.

And I am having one more issue with my code, when Exit button inside GUI is pressed, window will close however program is still running in background. I am using **self.Destroy()** function to kill all process.

Thank you for your advice.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import pyautogui
import wx
import threading
import sys
import win32api

class bucky(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        self.positionx = ""
        self.positiony = ""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'AutoClick 2.0', size=(300,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.buttonpos=wx.Button(panel,label="Left Screen",pos=(30,10),size=(80,40))
        self.buttonpos2=wx.Button(panel,label="Right Screen",pos=(180,10),size=(80,40))
        self.button=wx.Button(panel,label="Start",pos=(120,90),size=(60,30))
        self.button2=wx.Button(panel,wx.ID_EXIT,label="Exit",pos=(120,120),size=(60,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.action, self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closebutton, self.button2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.position, self.buttonpos)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.position, self.buttonpos2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.closewindow)


    def position(self, event):
        label = event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
        if label == "Left Screen":
            self.positionx = 1640
            self.positiony = 183
            self.buttonpos.Disable()
            self.buttonpos2.Enable()
        elif label == "Right Screen":
            self.positionx = 3308
            self.positiony= 186
            self.buttonpos.Enable()
            self.buttonpos2.Disable()

    def closebutton(self,event):
        self.Destroy()

    def closewindow(self,event):
        self.Destroy()

    def action(self,event):
        self.button.Disable()
        def callback():
            while 1:
                pos = pyautogui.position()
                time.sleep(10)
                pos1 = pyautogui.position()
                if (pos1[0] == pos[0]) and (pos1[1] == pos[1]):
                    win32api.SetCursorPos((self.positionx, self.positiony))
                    pyautogui.click()
                else:
                    pass
        t = threading.Thread(target=callback)
        t.start()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=bucky(parent=None,id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT: **Problem have been solved. Thank you for help.**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1i0v5y/hard_to_find_your_mouse_cursor_with_2_monitors/) post, I think the x coordinates for the secondary monitor are simply added to the resolution of the primary monitor (ex if you had two 1920x1080 monitors, the middle of the second monitor will be at 2880,520)

Try using `(win32api.GetSystemMetrics(MONITOR_NUMBER)` to see how the differences are represented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually here is some more information:
 screen size: 3360 x 1050, there are 2 monitors. You can see that Im defining coordinates  
self.positionx = 1640
self.positiony = 183 or
self.positionx = 3308
self.positiony= 186